# Did NIST edit WTC building 7 footage?

Tags: video, 9-11

According to Paul Joseph Watson [in this article](https://jamesfetzer.org/2010/10/suppressed-9-11-footage-explosions-brought-down-world-trade-center-building-7/), NIST, or some other government entity, edited footage of WTC building 7.  I'm not convinced of most of the claims, but [the video which is in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XH_Lv_sevwY) is clearly edited.  One frame, the penthouse on WTC-7 is there, on the next frame it's gone.  The smoke and onlookers are also in different positions, and there is a clear jump in the audio.

The video was uploaded by the International Center for 9/11 Studies. They claim on their website they got it from NIST via FOIA request.

Did the government edit this video, and if so, why?

Comment: It's clear there is a jump in video and audio but not in the time signature, but is that an indication of editing? Do you have anything relating to the source of the video? A mobile can take footage which later could be doctored to fuel conspiracy, so the provenance of the video would seem important to know.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. The video was uploaded by the International Center for 9/11 Studies.  They claim on their website they got it from NIST via FOIA request.

Comment: They got it from NIST, but there's nothing to suggest it was made by, or altered by NIST. If I download a YouTube video, and then you ask me to send you a copy of the file that I downloaded, does that magically mean I made the original video?  Does the Center for 9/11 Studies assume their computers were built from scratch in the back of Best Buy because that's where they purchased them?  It's impossible to evaluate the claim, because they offer nothing in terms of backup to their claim, at all. Voted to close.

Answer (score 18):

I'm going to quote from the comment of @Fizz.

> It seem the most obvious explanation is that the operator had stopped
> filming to save tape because nothing interesting was happening for a
> while. And when the building started falling they resumed... about a
> second too late to catch the initiation.

This is the explanation: the video was obtained from the government from the local NBC affiliate which had edited it for broadcast.

WTC 7 collapsed from the inside first; the first thing that was noticeable from external video was the penthouse disappearing into the roof.  The interior floors pancaked down and eventually dragged the exterior walls down with them; you can see this happening in the video linked in the question as the windows on the left of the top floors go empty before the building comes down.

The [University of Alaska's report](https://ine.uaf.edu/wtc7) linked in @Weather-Vane's comment includes a video from a different angle that shows the entire sequence uninterrupted.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a complete answer, but among the many videos at https://www.nist.gov/photos-videos-and-simulations there are several copies of the same footage that was used in the YouTube video.

`NBC1 Restricted clip_2.avi` in [Organized Photos and Video Clips / VideoClips / NBC Restricted - 2 Tapes / NBC Restricted Tape 1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yhgc-4uCwNr4Q55uvESe9Es79yzJEITE) and `NBC2␣Restricted␣tape␣clip_6.avi` in [NBC Restricted Tape 2](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Qjsc4rO6Ph_FXhIf2hXhmQHZSEpgqxzb) cover different time periods, but both contain the footage from the YouTube video, with the jump cut, but with no time code.

`WTC 7 part2 clip38.avi` in [Organized Photos and Video Clips / VideoClips / WTC 7 - 2 parts / WTC 7 Part 2](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t_nPi4oMa8eI9YZLdSLL5FXWlXaP6paF) is the portion after the jump cut, with a different time code.

Neither time code matches the time of the collapse in any time zone. They were obviously added later, and may just reflect the time the copy was made or its position on a longer tape.

I don't know why the jump cut existed in the first place, but as antlersoft's answer said, NBC may have just turned off the camera since nothing was happening, and there are other uninterrupted videos of the collapse.